# Display Error when using wx.grid's SetRowSize method

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to implement resizing multiple rows of a wx grid object when the user has multiple selected.  To do this, I do the following

```
def OnRowSize(self, event):
    """Row size event handler"""

    row = event.GetRowOrCol()
    rowsize = self.grid.GetRowSize(row)  # Get new size user wants for rows

    # Detect for resizing group of rows
    rows = self.grid.GetSelectedRows()
    if len(rows) == 0:
        rows = [row,]

    for row in rows:
        self.grid.SetRowSize(row, rowsize)

    event.Skip()
```

Lets says I have rows 1 through 5 selected.  When I resize row 1, everything works as intended.  When I resize row 3, rows 3 through 5 look fine but row 1 gets all messed up.  If I scroll down and back up again (forcing a refresh), everything looks ok.  Anyone know why this might be occuring?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Force a refresh of the grid by using:

```
self.grid.Refresh()
```